# C++ Makefile error - Class linkage not working in main file

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have just converted a program I've written from C to C++ and am having some issues with compiling from the Makefile. I am using two C++ header files (plus their implementation files) and one C header file.

The Makefile looks like this:

```
fplay: player.cpp audio.o video.o
    g++ $< -o $@ `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo libjpeg` -ldl -lm 

audio.o: audio.cpp audio.h
    g++ -c audio.cpp -lao -lsndfile

video.o: video.cpp video.h
    g++ -c video.cpp cairo_jpg.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo libjpeg`

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.o -f fplay
```

And the error (I assume this is a linker error) looks like this:

```
g++ -c audio.cpp -lao -lsndfile
g++ -c video.cpp cairo_jpg.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo libjpeg`
video.cpp: In member function ‘void Cairo::cairo_linuxfb_surface_create(const char*)’:
video.cpp:69:83: warning: converting from ‘void (Cairo::*)()’ to ‘void (*)(void*)’ [-Wpmf-conversions]
   69 |     cairo_surface_set_user_data(fbsurface, NULL, device, (void (*)(void*))&Cairo::cairo_linuxfb_surface_destroy);
      |                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
g++ player.cpp -o fplay `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo libjpeg` -ldl -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccX1hKEx.o: in function `main':
player.cpp:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `vidPlayer::vidPlayer(int, double, char*)'
/usr/bin/ld: player.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `audPlayer::audPlayer(char*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: player.cpp:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `vidPlayer::playVideo()'
/usr/bin/ld: player.cpp:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `audPlayer::playAudio()'
/usr/bin/ld: player.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `audPlayer::~audPlayer()'
/usr/bin/ld: player.cpp:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to `vidPlayer::~vidPlayer()'
/usr/bin/ld: player.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `audPlayer::~audPlayer()'
/usr/bin/ld: player.cpp:(.text+0x1e2): undefined reference to `vidPlayer::~vidPlayer()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccX1hKEx.o: in function `std::thread::thread<void (&)(), , void>(void (&)())':
player.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IRFvvEJEvEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IRFvvEJEvEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x33): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: fplay] Error 1
```

Ignore the warning, but for some reason even though I am creating and passing in the object files from the compiled headers, it is still not detecting the references in main. I don't have much experience with Makefiles, so I hope someone more experienced has the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: seems like ```player.cpp``` file can't find the file includes both ```vidPlayer``` and ```audPlayer``` classes.

Comment: video.h and audio.h are those files, which is why I am confused

Comment: Notice how your compilation line only includes player.cpp and not audio.o or video.o?  Look up what `$<` does.